# Why doesn't my code find any registry keys?

Tags: delphi, registry

I want to list USB VIDs from the registry, and I wrote the following Delphi code:

```
procedure FindUSBvids(VIDs: TStrings);
var
  Reg1: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg1 := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg1.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Reg1.OpenKey('System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB', False);
    Reg1.GetKeyNames(VIDs);
  finally
    Reg1.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
  FindUSBvids(Memo2.Lines);
end;
```

Unfortunately the Memo remains empty. I triple-checked the key, it exists and has a couple dozen subkeys. What am I doing wrong?

*(Note: I'm not sure this is the right way to find USB VIDs, but that's not the point. It's just that I'm puzzled why the code doesn't produce any result.)*

Comment: Small nitpick, Use CurrentControlSet instead of ControlSet001...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I think that's rather dependent on what OP is doing, don't you?  If debugging startup issues (for example) one might want to compare current with last known good... certainly one should never be *writing* to 001 or 002, but reading from them is a valid thing to do, at times.

Comment: @whosrdaddy That sounds like good advice, not nitpicking. Thanks!

Comment: @J..., the OP stated clearly he is checking for USB VIDS, so CurrentControlSet is more correct, no?

Comment: @whosrdaddy If they want to know what the current USB devices are, yes.  If, however, they want to compare with the last known good-boot config, then you have to query the backup set.  Like I said, it depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for write access to the registry key. Use `OpenKeyReadOnly` instead of `OpenKey`.

Comment: Alternatively, and maybe marginally safer, `Reg1 := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);`

Comment: Thanks David, that solves it. I already reposted your first answer (which you deleted, but the extra parameter is indeed not necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong originally. I thought that key is redirected, but it is not.

Comment: `KEY_READ` includes several access rights, not all of which the caller may have permission to use, depending on the particular security setup. `OpenKeyReadOnly()` is better to use than `OpenKey(KEY_READ)` because it tries several different combinations of access rights to give the caller a better chance of actual being able to open the key for reading. First it tries `KEY_READ`, if that fails than it tries `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ or KEY_QUERY_VALUE or KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`, if that fails then it tries `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`, and if that fails then it gives up.

Comment: Also, do make sure to check the return value of `OpenKey(ReadOnly)()` before calling `GetKeyNames()`. Don't try to enumerate the subkeys if the parent key fails to open.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your application with elevated access rights as administrator or as a normal user.

When you are using `OpenKey` Delphi by default tries to access that registry key using Read and Write access.

Now on Windows XP this would be just fine but on Windows Vista and newer this can be blocked by UAC especially if you are trying to read registry contents from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` part because this part of the registry is protected and requires elevated privileges to be modified.

So you need either to launch your application with administrative rights or change the `Access` property to `KEY_READ'. I would recommend using the lather if you are only enumerating the USB devices.

Comment: It's not fine on XP either. Standard user exists there too. It just wasn't as obvious when people got it wrong.